# Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS php 5.5 very common internal server error

Tags: ubuntu, internal-server-error, php-5.5

if a function has been called like

if ($this->_wordWrap(&$section)) {
    return; //word wrap has already taken care of calling addText
}

and function defination is like 
    private function _wordWrap($section) {

just change it like this

if ($this->_wordWrap($section)) {
    return; //word wrap has already taken care of calling addText
}

and function defination is like 
    private function _wordWrap(&$section) {

This will solve most of error related to internal server error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS php 5.5 very common internal server error

if a function has been called like

if ($this->_wordWrap(&$section)) { return; //word wrap has already taken care of calling addText }

and function defination is like private function _wordWrap($section) {

just change it like this

if ($this->_wordWrap($section)) { return; //word wrap has already taken care of calling addText }

and function defination is like private function _wordWrap(&$section) {

This will solve most of error related to internal server error